# It was authorized by Spring Security with error 404

Tags: kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm sending a Firebase token for Spring Security to validate, when making the request it was authorized successfully but generated a 404 error, and I can't understand why this happened. See how I placed the order with the image below.

[image]

Based on the console message, you can see that the request was authorized, but generated an error.

```
2023-09-26 10:47:46.574  INFO 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-26 10:47:46.574  INFO 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-09-26 10:47:46.575  INFO 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-09-26 10:47:46.581 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /users/extract-aud
2023-09-26 10:47:46.583 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=null, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]]
2023-09-26 10:47:46.584 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=null, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]]
2023-09-26 10:47:46.614 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [POST /users/extract-aud] with attributes [authenticated]
2023-09-26 10:47:46.614 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /users/extract-aud
2023-09-26 10:47:46.624 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=null, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@403e3460]
2023-09-26 10:47:46.625 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=null, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@403e3460]
2023-09-26 10:47:46.625 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-09-26 10:47:46.626 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2023-09-26 10:47:46.627 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=null, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]]
2023-09-26 10:47:46.627 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=null, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]]
2023-09-26 10:47:46.627 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error
2023-09-26 10:47:46.664 DEBUG 13013 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Could anyone make a suggestion to fix this problem in the Spring Security settings?

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
import javax.servlet.FilterChain
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

class JwtTokenFilter(private val jwtSecret: String) : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        val token = extractToken(request)
        if (token != null) {
            try {
                val audClaim = JWT.decode(token).getClaim("aud").asString()
                if (audClaim == "878452355642-fhjstsrsbbldkodudhhtmn0876.apps.googleusercontent.com") {
                    val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null, emptyList())
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authentication
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println(e)
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }

    private fun extractToken(request: HttpServletRequest): String? {
        val header = request.getHeader("Authorization")
        if (header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return header.substring(7)
        }
        return null
    }
}




package com.wladimir.bakery.BakeryOurDream.config

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Value("JKHSDKG0-oNselGYQy6IAGkjxEzI_jiouytyg") // Configure o segredo do JWT conforme necessário
    private lateinit var jwtSecret: String

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/extract-aud").authenticated() // Defina as regras de autorização conforme necessário
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtTokenFilter(): JwtTokenFilter {
        return JwtTokenFilter(jwtSecret)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your controller for the endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to the spring-security. The security checking already succeeded and so spring-security passes the HTTP request to spring-mvc to handle. However, spring-mvc finds that there are no endpoints has the URL `/users/extract-aud` and hence it returns `HTTP 404 Not Found` status code.

So you have to check the configurations related to spring-mvc (e.g  `@Controller` or `@RestController` or `WebMvcConfigurer` or `@EnableWebMvcConfiguration` etc.) , but not the spring-security configuration.